# Flask - commit FieldList to database using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, fieldlist

I am trying to commit fields generated from a FiedList but getting the error:
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'data'`

What I'm trying to do is add a list of fields to the database which I can then retrieve and display on the page.

```
#App.py

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = MainSubscriptionForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        for x in form.subscription:
            sub = Subscription(company=x.company.data, description=x.description.data)
            db.session.add(sub)
            db.session.commit()
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        list = Subscription.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', title="Home", form=form, list=list)
```

```
#forms.py

class SubscriptionForm(FlaskForm):
    company = StringField(('Company'), validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=0, max=20)])
    description = StringField(('Description'), validators=[Length(min=0, max=120)])
    save = SubmitField('Save')

class MainSubscriptionForm(FlaskForm):
    subscription = FieldList(FormField(SubscriptionForm), min_entries=1)
```

```
#models.py

class Subscription(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    company = db.Column(db.String(20))
    description = db.Column(db.String(120))
```

```
#index.html

{% extends "base.html" %}
{% from 'bootstrap/form.html' import render_form_row %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="post">
    {{ form.csrf_token() }}
       {% for sub in form.subscription %}
            {{ render_form_row(sub) }}
        {% endfor %}
    </form>
    {{ list }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that a dictionary was being sent and therefore it was crashing on the below line:

`sub = Subscription(company=x.company.data, description=x.description.data)`

The solution was to get the key value as per below:

`sub = Subscription(company=x.data['company'], description=x.data['description'])`